# Intellij 2016.3 update to Oracle 12c syntax

Tags: intellij-idea, oracle12c, intellij-idea-2016

After a recent upgrade to Oracle 12cR1, Idea's database-editor syntax-highlighting has gotten out-of-date for my Oracle connections.

Queries making use of 12c syntax that work fine in SQLPlus(12.1.0.2.0) and SQLcl(4.2.0) highlight as incorrect syntax in my Idea editor.  They also fail to run when executed from the editor.

I'd like to update intellij, but I haven't found where to upgrade the oracle dialect and my jdbc drivers appear to be up-to-date.  I was hoping for advice on two fronts--where to upgrade intellj to successfully execute 12c-syntax SQL, and how to get Idea's Oracle-Dialect to have 12c-compatible syntax highlighting.  An example that would cover both of these is subquery-factoring-clause function-declaration.  These constructs fail to execute for me in the editor with an ORA-06553.

I'm on Ubuntu-16.04 LTS with Idea (v 2016.3.4)
I'm using Database-Plugin: Database Tools and SQL plugin (v 1.0)
I'm using the provided drivers: .IntelliJIdea2016.3/config/jdbc-drivers/
Driver-versions are xdb6-12.1.0.2.jar and ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar
I'm not currently using any additional files in my driver configuration

If this isn't supported yet, I can accept that.  I'd just like to upgrade if currently possible.

Thanks

Here's an example for checking whether a string is on the (dvorak) home-row for typing.  The statement works fine in SQLPlus and SQLcl, but is flagged as invalid in Idea and fails to execute (ORA-06553).  This could of course be done more succinctly with SQL only, but hopefully illustrates the issue.

```
WITH
    FUNCTION IS_IT_DVORAK_HOME_ROW(P_CHAR_STRING IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS BEGIN
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(P_CHAR_STRING, '^[AOEUIDHTNS-aoeuidhtns_ ]{1,}$')
             THEN RETURN 1;
ELSE RETURN 0;
END CASE;
END;
SELECT DECODE(IS_IT_DVORAK_HOME_ROW('This And That And These and Those Too'),1,'Home-Row!','Nope...') AS HOME_ROWNESS
FROM DUAL;
/
```

Comment: It would be nice to see examples of 12c statements that DG is unable to parse

Comment: @kassak Sure thing, I'll add now.